# Install EFI-mode GRUB2 on Ubuntu booted from legacy-mode

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have searched for many posts and try some.
I would like to install EFI-mode GRUB on my USB hdd on Ubuntu, but methods I found did not work.
Finally I read a post that said EFI-mode GRUB can only be installed when Ubuntu was booted from EFI-mode, but not legacy-mode.
Yet I do not have Ubuntu DVD.
Thus I would like to ask if there are any solutions to to install EFI-mode GRUB when Ubuntu was booted from legacy-mode.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

See my [Managing EFI Boot Loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) page for information on this topic, and in particular the page on [installing boot loaders.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html) My rEFInd documentation page on [installing rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) goes into more detail for rEFInd, and you can adjust the critical commands for other boot programs, such as GRUB.

Doing it the "right" way requires an EFI-mode boot in order to register GRUB with the firmware; however, you can install the files from a legacy-mode boot and then use Windows, an EFI shell, or sometimes even the firmware's built-in user interface to register the boot program with the firmware.

Alternatively, you can give the boot program the name `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) This is a fallback filename for EFI-mode booting; if no other boot program is available, the firmware uses this filename. In fact, if you intend to move your USB device from one computer to another, this is the preferred way to do it, since then you won't need to register the boot loader with each computer's firmware.